# How to change username in wp admin bar

Tags: admin-bar

on the wp admin bar you want users to appear automatically after entering their first name and last name. I mean, name and last name in the upper right corner. How can I do this? As you can see in the picture, this is how it comes out when I choose it. I want users to exit automatically without selecting them. I found a few sources down there, but I don't know exactly how to do it. I would be glad if you help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995588/how-to-get-wordpress-users-first-name-from-wp-user-object

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

[first_name] & [last_name]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: For it to change immediatley as the user is typing in the input it would need to be done via Javascript, which implies that the user has changed their names, but this isn't true as they still have to click on save. Or maybe I've misunderstood?

Comment: Hello, there appears to be a username after logging into wordpress. If someone records their first name and last name, let it appear there. name and last name instead of username.

Comment: So you want to set their `user_nicename` or display name?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to set your display name automatically.